# How to filter columns whose all or some rows values are greater than 0 in Pandas data-frame using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have below data:
**df_day_1_matrix = df_day_1.pivot_table(columns='Time', index='Sensor_id', values='Temperature', fill_value= 0)
print(df_day_1_matrix)**

Table description: 5 * 465 i.e. 5 rows for sensor-id and 465 columns for different time.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Dataframe</h2>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Time/Sensor-id</th>
    <th>10:04:49</th> 
    <th>10:06:18</th>
    <th>10:07:18</th>
    <th>.........</th>
    <th>9:58:04</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>21.2204</td>
    <td>0.0000</td>
    <td>20.0121</td>
    <td>.......</td>
    <td>24.0100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>22.1201</td>
    <td>22.0101</td>
    <td>0.00000</td> 
    <td>.......</td>
    <td>22.0104</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>18.2204</td>
    <td>0.0000</td>
    <td>9.0222</td>
    <td>.......</td>
    <td>20.0200</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>19.2204</td>
    <td>0.0000</td>
    <td>19.0221</td>
    <td>.......</td>
    <td>0.0000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>27.2202</td>
    <td>12.022</td>
    <td>20.1121</td>
    <td>.......</td>
    <td>18.0100</td> 
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

So, here I need only those columns whose values are greater than 0 for at least 4 sensor-id from 2 to 6. Here, for e.g., I need time column after filter like :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Dataframe</h2>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Time/Sensor-id</th>
    <th>10:04:49</th> 
    
    <th>10:07:18</th>
    <th>.........</th>
    <th>9:58:04</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>21.2204</td>
    
    <td>20.0121</td>
    <td>.......</td>
    <td>24.0100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>22.1201</td>
    
    <td>0.00000</td> 
    <td>.......</td>
    <td>22.0104</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>18.2204</td>
    
    <td>9.0222</td>
    <td>.......</td>
    <td>20.0200</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>19.2204</td>
    
    <td>19.0221</td>
    <td>.......</td>
    <td>0.0000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>27.2202</td>
   
    <td>20.1121</td>
    <td>.......</td>
    <td>18.0100</td> 
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I get a new data-frame for the above scenario?

I'm going round in circles with this.

I've spent 60 minutes Googling but haven't been able to find what I need....

Answer (score 2):

```py
df.loc[:, df.gt(0).sum(axis=0).ge(4)]
```

You can first look at the values greater than 0 (`gt(0)`) over all the data frame, then count the number of such values per column (`sum(axis=0)`) and then again check whose counts are greater than or equal to 4 (`ge(4)`) and lastly select those with `loc`.

Comment: Thank you Mustafa for reply. But it is selecting all the columns because count is coming like:   
testing = df_day_1_matrix.gt(0).sum(axis=1)
print(testing)

Comment: hi @ArunKumarDey, Can you please try the edited code? It was reading `gt(4)` at the end which meant "greater than" but your requirement is "at least 4", so it should have been `ge(4)` i.e. "greater than or equal to".